# ListView and ObservableList in AndroidStudio

Tags: java, android, javafx, android-listview

I'm currently getting involved with app development in Android Studio. I have fairly much experience with JavaFX and I'm used to working with `Observables`.

The Question:
Is there an existing Android UI class/component that allows you to display the contents of an `ObservableList` such that it will automatically update when the ObservableList changes aside from explicit notification? (Mechanics like `ListView` and `Adapter` don't seem to work with `ObservableList`)

In general: Are Observables as much of a core component in Android as they are in JavaFX?